# Identity value for tables with 1 row vs no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a table (e.g. #test) with an identity column and insert 1 row into it and deleted the row with `DELETE FROM #test`. Then if I use `SELECT IDENT_CURRENT ( '#test' )` it returns 1. However, it also returns 1 if #test is a newly created / truncated table. Note, it doesn't matter if the row is deleted or not but for my case it will be empty tables.

Using `DBCC CHECKIDENT ( #test )` returns 1 for the 1 deleted row case and NULL for the newly created / truncated table case, but I can't find a way to capture its output (what I need is the identity value).

I am trying to set the identity value of other tables to the identity value of the old table (e.g. #test) + 1 (just 1 if the old table never had values inserted into it or was truncated), and I can't separate the 2 cases of 1 deleted row vs new / truncated table.

EDIT: as an example, you can use the following code:

```
create table #test (col1 int identity (1, 1))
dbcc checkident (#test)
select ident_current ( '#test' )
insert into #test default values
dbcc checkident (#test)
select ident_current ( '#test' )
drop table #test
```

dbcc checkident will return NULL and 1 whereas ident_current will return 1 and 1. (the output of dbcc checkident will be in the messages tab of SSMS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is set the identity value of another table equal to that of an old table, wouldn't something like this work?

```
declare @last_value int

select @last_value = last_value
from   sys.identity_columns
where  object_name(object_id) = 'old_table'

dbcc checkident (new_table, RESEED, @last_value)
```